# Can not understanding this html code for paging

Tags: html

I want to do some simple pagination of results but I don't have experience in client side development.
So I checked out how existing web sites do it via: `View Source` of `IE`.
In `youtube` I saw the following:
It displays 20 results per page and provides links for 7 pages.
The source is as follows:

```
<a href="/results?search_query=html+pagination&amp;page=1" class="yt-uix-button  yt-uix-pager-button yt-uix-button-toggled yt-uix-sessionlink yt-uix-button-default" data-sessionlink="ei=73WLUfrBCsaZ8gOtjoDYAw" data-page="1" <span class="yt-uix-button-content">1</span></a>   

<a href="/results?search_query=html+pagination&amp;page=2" class="yt-uix-button  yt-uix-pager-button yt-uix-sessionlink yt-uix-button-default" data-sessionlink="ei=73WLUfrBCsaZ8gOtjoDYAw" data-page="2" <span class="yt-uix-button-content">2</span></a>  

<a href="/results?search_query=html+pagination&amp;page=3" class="yt-uix-button  yt-uix-pager-button yt-uix-sessionlink yt-uix-button-default" data-sessionlink="ei=73WLUfrBCsaZ8gOtjoDYAw" data-page="3" <span class="yt-uix-button-content">3</span></a> 

<a href="/results?search_query=html+pagination&amp;page=4" class="yt-uix-button  yt-uix-pager-button yt-uix-sessionlink yt-uix-button-default" data-sessionlink="ei=73WLUfrBCsaZ8gOtjoDYAw" data-page="4" <span class="yt-uix-button-content">4</span></a>  

<a href="/results?search_query=html+pagination&amp;page=5" class="yt-uix-button  yt-uix-pager-button yt-uix-sessionlink yt-uix-button-default" data-sessionlink="ei=73WLUfrBCsaZ8gOtjoDYAw" data-page="5" <span class="yt-uix-button-content">5</span></a>  

<a href="/results?search_query=html+pagination&amp;page=6" class="yt-uix-button  yt-uix-pager-button yt-uix-sessionlink yt-uix-button-default" data-sessionlink="ei=73WLUfrBCsaZ8gOtjoDYAw" data-page="6" <span class="yt-uix-button-content">6</span></a> 

<a href="/results?search_query=html+pagination&amp;page=7" class="yt-uix-button  yt-uix-pager-button yt-uix-sessionlink yt-uix-button-default" data-sessionlink="ei=73WLUfrBCsaZ8gOtjoDYAw" data-page="7" <span class="yt-uix-button-content">7</span></a>  

<a href="/results?search_query=html+pagination&amp;page=2" class="yt-uix-button  yt-uix-pager-button yt-uix-sessionlink yt-uix-button-default" data-sessionlink="ei=73WLUfrBCsaZ8gOtjoDYAw" data-page="2"><span class="yt-uix-button-content">Next »</span></a>
```

So I assume that `sessionlink` is like a session identifier?
How could I use that in my server side code?
Also why does `Next` refers to `/results?search_query=html+pagination&amp;page=2`?

Comment: Its hard to understand what you are asking. Its a simple pagination model... the query in the URL &amp;page=2 refers to a page number. The query is proccessed and results from page 2 are retrieved from the server and displayed.

Comment: Because the next page is number 2. Hrefs are certainly refering to some kind of server-side script like php or cgi. `yt-uix-sessionlink` is a css class, look into the css file.

Comment: @Rubelet:What is `&amp` used for?

Comment: @Jim Its a HTML entity to represent & symbol. It is a separator for parameters in a query.

Comment: Everthing after ? is a key-value pair you can use in your file that handles things. If you use more than one variable to send to your file you bind the different key-value couples with $amp;

Answer (score 0):

This can be still simplified this way:

```
<a href="paged?page=1">« Prev</a>
<a href="paged?page=1">1</a>
<a href="paged?page=2">2</a>
<a href="paged?page=3">3</a>
<a href="paged?page=3">Next »</a>
```

Just for the pure pagination part, you don't need to worry about session identifiers. There is this `GET` variable called `page` that passes the page number to the `paged` page.

Comment: What about the `sessionlink`?

Comment: Depends on the app. If the app requires, then yes. Not needed for just pagination alone.

Comment: This is understandable for 3 links.What happens when the user presses `Next` or `Prev`?

Comment: @Jim Could you see that the Next and Previous have the same links of page 3 and 1 respectively?

Comment: Yes but this is not how it would be done in a page that has hundrends of results, right?

Comment: There is no difference. But only thing is, you would be skipping some page numbers. That's all.

Comment: But how would I know which pages are visible and which should be the `Previous` and which `Next` at any moment?

Comment: @Jim That's your call / wish. You can have like current page ± 5 pages.

Comment: Yes this is my question. How do I know which pages are visible and to display next? Via the `sessionlink`?

Comment: Not via the session link, but via the current page! Dude, I guess there's nothing more to explain! Rather I can give you the full code!!!

Comment: May be this explanation is clear to someone else but I don't have experience in front end. So not sure how the current page helps. You mean read the current value from a field of the page?

Comment: Yes. And that is given by the `page` parameter.

Comment: Ok.But the `page` parameter, shouldn't it be kept in some scope among requests? This goes to session? I mean somehow we must calculate that we should display `3,4,5` instead of `1,2,3` right?

Comment: Why are you confusing this with the sessions?

Comment: I am not sure how you would think I would be helped by mere hints. I told in the OP that I don't have experience in client side

Comment: Thanks for this extra hint